# In UI service how to get the content of a RichTextArea?

Tags: google-apps-script

Class RichTextArea has no setName() so I'm wondering how to use its content in a Handler function.
the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_richtextarea?hl=fr-FR) refers to the Google Web Toolkit but I can't get how to make that work in GAS.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an issue on the tracker reported by Saurabh himself.
[Issue 504: RichTextArea#setName does not exist](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=504)

But from the looks of the report, they don't seem to be working on it. So, I guess all we can do for now is just star this issue and leave comments on it trying to raise the attention.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, hmmmm...too bad... any idea how to create some user friendly way to create html email body ? I mean not by hard coding and for people completely unable to use html tags.

Comment: Let them do it on Gmail and fetch the draft from the script? (btw, I plan to do this for FormEmailer's next version)

Comment: Thanks, I saw your comment on the issue tracker and I agree : it doesn't seem to be moving ... let's hope they will fix it ...